# How exactly does the "parent" function from HTML::TreeBuilder work?

Tags: html, perl, module, tree, html-tree

The [documentation on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aElement) doesn't really explain this behavior unless I'm missing something. I've put together some quick test code to illustrate my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $testHtml = " 
<body>
        <h1>
                <p> 
                        <p>HELLO!
                        </p> 
                </p> 
        </h1>
</body>";

my $parsedPage = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$parsedPage->parse($testHtml);
$parsedPage->eof();

my @p = $parsedPage->look_down('_tag' => 'p');

foreach (@p) {print $_->parent->tag, " : ", $_->tag, "\t", $_->as_text, "\n";}
```

After running the above script, the output is:

```
body : p

body : p        HELLO!
```

Seeing as all the tags are nested one after another, I would think that the parent of the first `p` tag would be `h1`, and the parent of the second `p` tag would be `p`.  Why is the parent function showing the `body` tag for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. And given that HTML::TreeBuilder is a subclass of HTML::Parser, I can only assume that the parser is doing what it can to transform your document into valid HTML.

You can call $parsedPage->as_HTML to see what the parser has done to your HTML. It gives me this:

```
<html><head></head><body><h1></h1><p><p>HELLO! </body></html>
```

Perhaps you should pass your HTML through a validator or HTML::Tidy, before processing it.

Comment: hmmm, the sample is only a sort of recreation of some HTML I need to parse.  I'm not sure what the best way of dealing with invalid HTML would be...

Comment: Actually, HTML::Parser doesn't know or care what tags are allowed to nest inside each other.  All it does is recognize start tags, end tags, text, etc. It's HTML::TreeBuilder that takes the events generated by HTML::Parser and constructs a validly nested tree.  It tries to deal with invalid HTML in the same way most browsers do.